# SQL Server on kubernetes: an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run SQL Server on my local Docker Desktop instance, and when run in Kubernetes mode, I get a strange error. Is there an error in my k8s.yaml file?

If I start it with `docker-compose up` and this yaml, it works fine:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=C@mpl3xEn0#gh!
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    network_mode: bridge
```

Then I test the connection with `sqlcmd -U sa -P C@mpl3xEn0#gh! -S localhost,1433` and it connects just fine.

If I start it with `kubectl apply -f k8s.yaml` following the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-sql-server-containers-kubernetes I get an error connecting:

```
# based loosely on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-sql-server-containers-kubernetes#create-the-deployment
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  containers:
  - name: db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 1433
    env:
    - name: ACCEPT_EULA
      value: 'Y'
    - name: SA_PASSWORD
      value: C@mpl3xEn0#gh!
    resources: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: db
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
```

Then I try to connect from my local machine using `sqlcmd -U sa -P C@mpl3xEn0#gh! -S localhost,31043` (swapping in the NodePort from `kubectl get svc/db`), and I get the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I get the same error from Azure Data Studio and SSMS.

If I `kubectl exec ...` into the container and run `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P C@mpl3xEn0#gh! -S localhost,1433` it connects just fine.

Where's the error in my k8s.yaml file that causes SQL Server not accept connections when run in Kubernetes?

I've tried setting `encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;` and results don't change.

Comment: It seems that the image has a TLS version that is not compatible to make the handshake. Did you tried to change or remove the type of the service or fetch another image version?

Comment: How interesting. Where did you find this info @StPaulis? I haven't tried another version, though I'll give it a try. Which version would you recommend?

Comment: I had the same issue on a swarm cluster, long time ago. The difference was that I was using a slim image of SQL and turn it to the normal, solved my problem. I am not sure that is the same issue, but the error match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo gets me again.  Here's the missing piece of yaml:

```
...
metadata:
  name: db
  labels: # <--
    app: db # <--
spec:
...
```

I forgot the `labels:` part.  So the service carefully forwarded the traffic on to nothing, which didn't do a TLS handshake, and yielded me the erroneous error.